# Is this solvable using sympy? - no output after 1 day

Tags: sympy, physics, calculus

The original question:
[image]

My approach: The electric field is already given in the textbook as

```
\begin{equation}
  E(x, y, z) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[ 
\frac{\hat{x}x + \hat{y}y + \hat{z}(z - z_0)}{(x^2 + y^2 + (z - z_0)^2)^{3/2}} + 
\frac{\hat{x}x + \hat{y}y + \hat{z}(z + z_0)}{(x^2 + y^2 + (z + z_0)^2)^{3/2}} 
\right]
\end{equation}
```

So I used this equation in the textbook:

```
\begin{equation}
  U=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int E^2d^3\!x=
\end{equation}
```

To calculate this, I asked GPT-4 to write a python program to compute this using `sympy`. Below is the code:

```
from sympy import *

# Define the symbols
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
q = symbols('q', real=True, positive=True)
epsilon_0 = symbols('epsilon_0', real=True, positive=True)
z0 = symbols('z0', real=True, positive=True)

# Electric field components due to the image charges
E1_x = q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * x / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z - z0)**2)**(3/2))
E1_y = q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * y / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z - z0)**2)**(3/2))
E1_z = q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * (z - z0) / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z - z0)**2)**(3/2))

E2_x = q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * x / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z + z0)**2)**(3/2))
E2_y = q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * y / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z + z0)**2)**(3/2))
E2_z = -q / (4 * pi * epsilon_0) * (z + z0) / ((x**2 + y**2 + (z + z0)**2)**(3/2))

# Total electric field components
E_x = E1_x + E2_x
E_y = E1_y + E2_y
E_z = E1_z + E2_z

# Squaring the electric field components and summing them
E_squared = E_x**2 + E_y**2 + E_z**2

# Integrate E_squared over the half-space where z > 0
U = (epsilon_0 / 2) * integrate(integrate(integrate(E_squared, (x, -oo, oo)), (y, -oo, oo)), (z, 0, oo))

U.simplify()
```

I ran the code and expected to get a result in some day. I've left it running for around 1-2 days and there is no output. It is constantly using 100% CPU (I have 8P+2E cores). I'm not sure if this is not solvable in `sympy` or is it just really complicated.

Comment: I doubt if it even stands a chance given the way you have set it up to fail on a double integral to infinity. It might if it understands certain types of complex number integration tricks but not as written out above in 3D. You are supposed to exploit the conductive boundary condition having zero potential all over its surface and a bit of physical intuition. Symbolic algebra systems are very good at manipulating symbols error free but they have no intuition and can only try to solve the problem that you set them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has axial symmetry, around the axis from the point charge to the ground plane (and perpendicular to the ground plane).

You need to convert it to cylindrical or 2d polar coordinates that explot the symmetry, rather than cartesian. The triple integral in cartesian coordinates becomes a double integral in cylindrical coordinates which would probably work in sympy.

Alternately, you can use the method of images https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_images and consider two point charges rather than a point charge and ground plane.  That system still has cylindrical symmetry and the double integral is probably calculable by hand - look at a few textbooks to see if there is a worked example.

[image]